# CSS mostra apenas parte dos elementos de uma DIV

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0; 
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
}
div.cabecalho {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
div.cabecalho > div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div.cabecalho div img{
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
div.cabecalho div.logo {
    width:42%;
}
div.cabecalho div.menu {
    display:none;
}
div.cabecalho div.redes {
    width:57%;
}
div.cabecalho div.redes div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:32%;
}
div.cabecalho div.logo img {
    -webkit-animation : logo-anim 1s;
    -moz-animation : logo-anim 1s;
    -o-animation : logo-anim 1s;
    animation : logo-anim 1s;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes logo-anim {
 0% {
 opacity : 0;
 transform : translateY(-50px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -o-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(-50px);
}
 100% {
 opacity : 1;
 transform : translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(0px);
 -o-transform : translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(0px);
}
}
 @-moz-keyframes logo-anim {
 0% {
 opacity : 0;
 transform : translateY(-50px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -o-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(-50px);
}
 100% {
 opacity : 1;
 transform : translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(0px);
 -o-transform : translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(0px);
}
}
 @-o-keyframes logo-anim {
 0% {
 opacity : 0;
 transform : translateY(-50px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -o-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(-50px);
}
 100% {
 opacity : 1;
 transform : translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(0px);
 -o-transform : translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(0px);
}
}
 @keyframes logo-anim {
 0% {
 opacity : 0;
 transform : translateY(-50px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -o-transform : translateY(-50px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(-50px);
}
 100% {
 opacity : 1;
 transform : translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform : translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform : translateY(0px);
 -o-transform : translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform : translateY(0px);
}
}

div.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
}
div.menu ul.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    background-color: rgb(36,81,60);
}
div.menu ul.menu li {
    width:16.5%;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
div.menu ul.menu li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(25,57,42);      
}
div.menu ul.menu li a{
    width:100%;
    line-height:70px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:1.7vw;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
div.banner {
}

@media screen and (max-width:860px) {

    div.cabecalho > div {
        width:100% !important;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:320px)  {  
    div.menu, 
    div.banner {
        display:none;
    }

    div.cabecalho > div {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    div.cabecalho div.redes {
        display:none;
    }
    div.cabecalho > div.logo {
        width:72%;
    }
    div.cabecalho div.redes2 {
        width:12%;
    }   
    div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div{
        display:block;
    }

    div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div img{
        width:50%;
    }

    div.cabecalho > div.menu {
        width:12%;
        height:100%;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }


}
```

Quando reduzo a resolução para menor que 320px, ocorrem alguns problemas:

1) embora eu faça a Media Query abaixo:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px)  {  
    div.menu, 
    div.banner {
        display:none;
    }

    div.cabecalho > div {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    div.cabecalho div.redes {
        display:none;
    }
    div.cabecalho > div.logo {
        width:72%;
    }
    div.cabecalho div.redes2 {
        width:12%;
    }   
    div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div{
        display:block;
    }

    div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div img{
        width:50%;
    }

    div.cabecalho > div.menu {
        width:12%;
        height:100%;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }


}
```

apenas a `div.cabecalho > div.logo` é mostrada na tela, e mesmo assim com **100%** e não com os **72%** declarados.

Os 2 outros **blocos**, `div.redes2` e `div.menu` da `div.cabecalho` não estão sendo mostradas mas parece que estão ocupando o lugar. Muito parecido com `opacity:0`

Onde estou errando?

Em tempo: sem erros ou avisos no depurador!

***PODE SER VISUALIZADO EM*** http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo

Comment: Seu link de exemplo, está com erro no php. Pode verificar?

Comment: desculpe era que ainda estava subindo a atualização para o ftp. Pode dar f5 ai

Comment: Carlos para que vc quer uma resolução inferior a 320px? Seu site precisa ser exibido em um Apple Watch ou em algum outro relógio smart? 320px já é o mínimo, qq tela menor que isso provavelmente será de algum dispositivo antigo no qual o Browser também será antigo e não deve dar suporte a metade do seu CSS, eu particularmente não me preocuparia com telas menores que 320px...

Comment: exemplo: eu tenho um Sony Xperia E, pequeno, 320px; Mas o problema não é esse. Preciso saber onde está o erro para não comete-lo novamente. Entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o CSS abaixo. Acredito que o problema só esta na ordem que você chama o css ou styles definidos no proprio elemento, então vai precisar usar `!important` em algumas propriedades:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px)  {  
div.menu, 
div.banner {
    display:none;
}

div.cabecalho > div {
    display:inline-block!important;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

div.cabecalho div.redes {
    display:none!important;
}
div.cabecalho > div.logo {
    width:72%!important;
}
div.cabecalho div.redes2 {
    width:12%!important;
}   
div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div{
    display:block;
}

div.cabecalho div.redes2 > div img{
    width:50%;
}

div.cabecalho > div.menu {
    width:12%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

}

Comment: kkk, você não vai acreditar: O meu código estava exatamente igual ao que você postou. Mas eu retirei os !important para elaborar a pergunta. O mesmo erro (falha) que eu cometi você também cometeu. o elemento     div.cabecalho > div.menu {
        width:12%; também preicisa do !important senão ele NÃO se alinha aos outros elementos. Mas mesmo assim a tua resposta me ajudou a descobrir a falha. Vou aceitá-la!

Comment: Hahaha boaa. Vlw